# Is there a way to update textarea 2 simultaneously while typing text in text area 1 using JSF ajax features?

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2, i have a requirement where i have to update second textearea while i am typing in textarea 1.

```
 TextArea1: <h:inputTextArea  maxlength="100" id="myTextarea" value="" />
 TextArea2:<h:inputTextArea  maxlength="100" id="output" value="" />
```

can someone help me out on this, though using jquery we can achieve this but i am looking for ajax component facility from JSF ?

Comment: @BalusC thanks it worked . Just want to know that can we achieve this without using js or jquery. Can we use some JSF ajax component to achieve this ?

Comment: You should have clearly stated that in your question...

Comment: And what do you think the Ajax components use behind the scenes?  The 'dogma' that everything should be done with jsf components is as bad as the one that everything should be done with new hyped  JavaScript frameworks  just use best of both worlds